# MTP Device is connected and recognised but not displayed in file manager in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, nautilus, android, mtp

My phone Lenovo Vibe P1 is no longer getting displayed in my File manager in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

It is getting displayed without error in my brothers pc which is also running Ubuntu 14.04.

It used to get displayed earlier in my pc too, but recently after the updates it is not getting displayed. Earlier I was able to mount and open windows partition, but now i am unable to do that too.

I checked with the 'lsusb' command in terminal, the device is recognised as a Lenovo.

Could this be an error with Nautilus? If so help me fix it. It would save me the time to reinstall. Thanks.